# C++ CtreeCtrl vertical scroll bar not scrolling till down button

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have a CTreeCtrl in my simple dialog where Root, Level 1 and Level2 items are inserted and are drawn in OnPaint with Multiple lines.

The problem is that the last item in the tree control is not visible completely. When scrolling down the vertical scroll bar, it is going back to the previous position.

In the image shown, Even if I click on down scroll button, the scroll position is not coming down.

Appreciate if any one can help me on this.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Here is the Custom draw code.

Comment: void zcbTreeControl::OnNMCustomdraw(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
if (pCustomDraw->nmcd.dwDrawStage == ( CDDS_ITEMPOSTPAINT))
{
GetItemRect((HTREEITEM)pCustomDraw->nmcd.dwItemSpec, &rcItem, TRUE);
// Fill the whole rect with white color
dc.Attach(pCustomDraw->nmcd.hdc);
hItem = (HTREEITEM)pCustomDraw->nmcd.dwItemSpec;
csItem = GetItemText(hItem);
dc.DrawText(csItem, &rcItem, DT_WORDBREAK | DT_CALCRECT);
if (pCustomDraw->nmcd.uItemState & CDIS_FOCUS);
//fill selection color
dc.DrawText(csItem, rcItem, DT_WORDBREAK | DT_VCENTER);
dc.Detach();
*pResult = CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT;
}
}

Comment: This is the custom draw code which draws multiline items.

Comment: I am still seeing the vertical scroll issue here.

Comment: Awaiting for help as this is priority one for me. Appreciate your help and understanding.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.